# Creating a new date variable that is on the same day of the week, within the same month, and year as original date variable in r

Tags: r, date

I need to create a new variable "controldates" from a date variable "casedates". This new variable is going to consist of dates that are on the same day of the week as the casedate, within the same month and year as the case date. For example if I have a case date on the 3rd Wednesday of July my control days will be the first 1st Wednesday of July, the second Wednesday of July, and the 4th Wednesday of July. Additionally, I would like to create an indicator variable for each group of dates that are created. I would like to do this using dplyr in r.

Starting data:

```
Casedate
 "01-03-2015"
 "08-27-2017"
 "10-23-2019"
```

This is how I would like it to look

```
Casedate          Controldate      Index
"01-03-2015"      "01-03-2015"       1
"01-03-2015"      "01-10-2015"       1
"01-03-2015"      "01-17-2015"       1
"01-03-2015"      "01-24-2015"       1
"01-03-2015"      "01-31-2015"       1
"08-12-2017"      "08-05-2017"       2
"08-12-2017"      "08-12-2017"       2
"08-12-2017"      "08-19-2017"       2
"08-12-2017"      "08-26-2017"       2
"10-23-2019"      "10-02-2019"       3
"10-23-2019"      "10-09-2019"       3
"10-23-2019"      "10-16-2019"       3
"10-23-2019"      "10-23-2019"       3
"10-23-2019"      "10-30-2019"       3
```

Comment: Your second date input is `"08-27-2017"` ,  but in the output it was showed as `"08-12-2017"`

Comment: This was a typo. Thank you for bringing it to my attention. The input should be 8-12-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`. Convert the 'Casedate' to `Date` class with `lubridate`, then loop over the elements with `map`, create a `seq`uence of dates in a `list`, `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Index = row_number(), 
      Casedate = mdy(Casedate), 
     wd = wday(Casedate, label = TRUE), 
     Controldate = map2(floor_date(Casedate, 'month'), wd, ~ {
   x1 <- seq(.x, length.out = 7, by = '1 day')
    seq(x1[wday(x1, label = TRUE) == .y],
       ceiling_date(.x, 'month'), by = '7 day')})) %>% 
    unnest(c(Controldate)) %>%
    select(Casedate, Controldate, Index)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
#   Casedate   Controldate Index
#   <date>     <date>      <int>
# 1 2015-01-03 2015-01-03      1
# 2 2015-01-03 2015-01-10      1
# 3 2015-01-03 2015-01-17      1
# 4 2015-01-03 2015-01-24      1
# 5 2015-01-03 2015-01-31      1
# 6 2017-08-27 2017-08-06      2
# 7 2017-08-27 2017-08-13      2
# 8 2017-08-27 2017-08-20      2
# 9 2017-08-27 2017-08-27      2
#10 2019-10-23 2019-10-02      3
#11 2019-10-23 2019-10-09      3
#12 2019-10-23 2019-10-16      3
#13 2019-10-23 2019-10-23      3
#14 2019-10-23 2019-10-30      3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Casedate = c("01-03-2015", "08-27-2017", "10-23-2019"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Do you need the `c(Controldate)` or will just `Controldate` do it for the `unnest` statement?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried running this on my data and it gives the error: 
  Error in seq.int(from, by = by, length.out = length.out) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
   In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: I got it to run when I removed the Casedate=mdy(Casedate). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since there can only at most be 4 weeks prior or 4 weeks after a date within a month (9 values total), you can get away with calculating that range all in one go with some sequences. That should avoid the need for looping over every value explicitly.

After calculating the values, then subset to those in the same month as the original value in a single sweep. Using @akrun's `df1` example data from below:

```
d  <- as.Date(df1$Casedate, format="%m-%d-%Y")
r  <- rep(d, each=9)
o  <- r + (7 * -4:4)
i  <- rep(seq_along(d), each=9)
s  <- format(o, "%m") == format(r, "%m")

data.frame(
    Casedate = r,
    Controldate = o,
    Index = i
)[s,]

#     Casedate Controldate Index
#5  2015-01-03  2015-01-03     1
#6  2015-01-03  2015-01-10     1
#7  2015-01-03  2015-01-17     1
#8  2015-01-03  2015-01-24     1
#9  2015-01-03  2015-01-31     1
#11 2017-08-27  2017-08-06     2
#12 2017-08-27  2017-08-13     2
#13 2017-08-27  2017-08-20     2
#14 2017-08-27  2017-08-27     2
#20 2019-10-23  2019-10-02     3
#21 2019-10-23  2019-10-09     3
#22 2019-10-23  2019-10-16     3
#23 2019-10-23  2019-10-23     3
#24 2019-10-23  2019-10-30     3
```

If you want to keep all of the original variables in the dataset, it is a simple fix:

```
cbind(
  df1[i,],
  data.frame(Controldate = o, Index = i)
)[s,]
```

E.g.:

```
#      Casedate othvar1 othvar2 Controldate Index
#1.4 01-03-2015       a       B  2015-01-03     1
#1.5 01-03-2015       a       B  2015-01-10     1
#1.6 01-03-2015       a       B  2015-01-17     1
#1.7 01-03-2015       a       B  2015-01-24     1
#...
```

Even on a moderately large dataset (300K rows), there is a meaningful difference in timing between generating sequence runs (2 seconds) and looping over each value (2 minutes):

Sequence:

```
df1 <- df1[rep(1:3,each=1e5),,drop=FALSE]

system.time({
d  <- as.Date(df1$Casedate, format="%m-%d-%Y")
r  <- rep(d, each=9)
o  <- r + (7 * -4:4)
i  <- rep(seq_along(d), each=9)
s  <- format(o, "%m") == format(r, "%m")

data.frame(
    Casedate = r,
    Controldate = o,
    Index = i
)[s,]
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.909   0.128   2.038
```

Looping:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

system.time({
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Index = row_number(), 
      Casedate = mdy(Casedate), 
     wd = wday(Casedate, label = TRUE), 
     Controldate = map2(floor_date(Casedate, 'month'), wd, ~ {
   x1 <- seq(.x, length.out = 7, by = '1 day')
    seq(x1[wday(x1, label = TRUE) == .y],
       ceiling_date(.x, 'month'), by = '7 day')})) %>% 
    unnest(Controldate) %>%
    select(Casedate, Controldate, Index)
})

#    user  system elapsed 
# 131.466   1.143 132.623
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wanted to use dplyr because I have a dataframe that has 24 other variables that I would like to keep. I'd rather not have to merge the resulting dataframe back to the original, incase I have duplicate case dates from different participants.

Comment: @Sara - that's no biggy - see my update. This method already generates a row index you can use to get all the additional variables returned that might already be in your dataset.